# iterate on sets of string in java

Tags: java, string, algorithm

i have program that makes operations on string **and this is the principal function** of one of those operations,this works perfectly,but it is not efficient:

```
private void printString(ArrayList<String> operations, ArrayList<String> set) {
    int numerOfStrings = 0;
    int numberOfletters = 0;
    String toPrint = operations.get(1);
    outOfLoop: for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
        String[] toFind = set.get(i).split(" ");
        for (int k = 0; k < toFind.length; k++) {
        if (toPrint.equals(toFind[k])) {
            String[] splited = set.get(i).split(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j < splited.length; j++) {
            numberOfletters += splited[j].length();
            }
            numerOfStrings = splited.length;
            break outOfLoop;
        }
      }  
    }
    System.out.println(numerOfStrings + " " + numberOfletters);
    }
```

explanation:

this function takes as parameter a an arrayList of operations, and an arraylist of set:

1. *for the `arraylist of operations` i get always a specific position so,i don't iterate , it is always `O(1)`*
2. for the *arrayList* of set i have to iterate,or rather, as I think of that to proceed:

   so , for example, if have as operation `print foo` i have to do these steps:

   - ***first of all i have to find where foo is :***

     - *inside `set` i can have this situation:*

       ```
       position 1 : {car tree hotel}
       ...
       position n : {foo lemon coffee}
       ```
     - *when i find the string `foo` i have to print the number of strings inside that position and the number of letters of each string,so in this case i will print :*

       ***3(number of strings)  14(number of letters)***

*my program works,and also this function works, but  it is a nasty solution,and not efficent,what do you think, how can I improve in efficiency in my program?*

question inserted on [code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52632/concat-strings-in-java)

Comment: -> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question belongs on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: `toFind` and `splited` contain equal arrays, is this intentional?

Comment: @olrC: I saw that break label after so long :). plus tofind & splitted have same values without any further change in their states (readonly, so why use two copies). You can also try to reduce your loops (there are 3 of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this version:

```
private void printString(ArrayList<String> operations, ArrayList<String> set) {
        int numerOfStrings = 0;
        int numberOfletters = 0;
        String toPrint = operations.get(1);
        for (String s : set) {
            if (s.contains(toPrint)) {
                String[] arr = s.split(" ");
                numerOfStrings = arr.length;
                numberOfletters = s.length() - (numerOfStrings - 1);
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(numerOfStrings + " " + numberOfletters);
    }
```

The 'worst' case here would be O(n2), because of for loop O(n) and contains O(n).
hope it helps.

Comment: good solution,better than mine.